# Creating Copy of file over a network share

Tags: java, file, networking, copy

We have an enterprise application which saves some files on a network share (\\physicalfileserver\files\). We need to use a network share because the application is installed on multiple application server instances distributed over multiple physical server connected via LAN. Sometimes, we need to create a copy of certain files on the network share itself and save it in same the directory (on the same network share) with a different name or in a new directory (Again on the same network share). What is the most efficient way to create a copy of the file? I do not want to create any IO traffic on the network as the source and destination files reside on the same server. It also increases the time taken to create a copy of the file. This however, is difficult from What I have seen so far.

- Reading files in input stream and writing them back on the server through an output stream with a different path/name.
- FileUtils.copyFile() from apache commons.
- NIO Channels library of JAVA (java.nio.channels.FileChannel.transferFrom())

However, all of them seem to copy the file to the server executing the program and then copy the data back to network share which isn't really required.

What can the gurus suggest to be the best possible approach to handle this situation? I can only use JAVA 1.5/1.6 due to some restrictions but am open to suggestions using higher java version as well.

The application is installed on a Windows 2008 server and the network share is also present on a Windows 2008 server.

Thanks

Comment: If you're worried about network bandwidth issues, try having a command on the server where the network share exists that can be instructed to copy the file on your behalf, then the copy is done locally to the machine.

Comment: What server/os is it?  What about rexec?

Comment: Thanks. I am considering that but wanted to keep it as a last resort because the application is multi platform and I do not want to create any platform specific dependencies. The copy works really fats if I use NFS or GFS mount instead in Unix but the issue is mainly for Windows so I was wondering if there is any way I could solve it through java only.

Comment: The application ins installed on Windows server 2008 and the network share is also on Windows server 2008. If I use NFS mount on a Unix machine, it works very well but the program slows down on Windows environments.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid network traffic you could write a small server in Java that would allow you to copy files locally (this would run on file server itself). Securing this would be quite important as this could pose huge security risk if somebody could use it to overwrite system files.

Comment: I assume there is no alternative in JAVA to remotely copy the file then? rexec would be a great help as @Leor suggested but I can't seem to find any java api implementations which would use the native OS functions of the server where I am copying the the files to/from.

Comment: There isn't one I could think of. Since you have domain setup there you could potentially run commands remotely on file servers. There is Microsoft tool called PsExec http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx that might be of use.